# SQL query based on the time

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting, date-arithmetic

The below is the table:

```
ID_NO        in_time                 out_time
S162Z       02-JUL-10 08.00.00  02-JUL-10 16.00.00
S162Z       07-OCT-10 10.00.00  08-OCT-10 13.00.00
S162Z       23-FEB-11 08.00.00  23-FEB-11 16.00.00
S162Z       01-FEB-14 09.00.00  12-FEB-14 18.00.00
S162Z       26-NOV-15 08.00.00  27-NOV-15 10.00.00
S682D       03-NOV-14 08.00.01  03-NOV-14 08.00.01
S801C       28-NOV-15 08.00.00  -
S801C       07-OCT-10 10.00.00  -
S801C       23-FEB-11 08.00.00  -
```

I want to find those id_no who have out time greater than 24 hours based on the in_time of particular month.

Like i want to find those ids  based on the below conditions

1) who have out-time greater than 24 hrs based on the in-time for the 'mmyyyy' = '112015'. and also

2) who have no out-time for the particular month 'mmyyyy' = '112015'.

Sample output:

`S162Z     26-NOV-15 08.00.00  27-NOV-15 10.00.00`

```
S801C       28-NOV-15 08.00.00  -
```

Comment: To give you some feedback, what is the format of the `in_time` and `out_time` columns?  You can simply take the difference between these columns once you get over the formatting issue.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen    The in-time and out-time are in the date format.

Comment: ...and what have you tried?

Comment: Format is irrelevant if the datatype of the column is appropriate (i.e. some kind of date data type). @testuser please indicate the datatype of each column.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid OP has already mentioned the datatype to be DATE.

Comment: "date format" <> "datatype". The definition remains ambiguous particularly since the sample data contains a time portion. It's a bad idea to make assumptions!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Ah! I see what you mean. OP said they are in date format. That doesn't mean it is date data type. Sorry, my bad eyes early morning. I added a note to my answer "*Assuming the data type of your in_time and out_time column to be DATE*"

Comment: Personally I prefer to clarify these things before posting an answer otherwise you might waste your time. In fact a poster asking a database question that doesn't understand what a data type is probably won't be able to make sense of the correct answer.

Comment: I'm guessing @testuser has abandoned the question.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid   the in_time and out_time are in " DATE" data type

Comment: I'm glad you came back and confirmed it. I suggest you try out the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) who have out-time greater than 24 hrs based on the in-time for the 'mmyyyy' = '112015'

You could use **TO_CHAR** to compare `MMYYYY` and then subtract `out_time` and `in_time` to check if the difference is greater than `24 hours` i.e. 1 day.

> 2) who have no out-time for the particular month 'mmyyyy' = '112015'.

It should be a simple `IS NULL` condition.

Assuming the data type of your `in_time` and `out_time` column to be **DATE**, your filter predicate would be:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(in_time, 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(out_time, 'MMYYYY')
AND out_time                     > in_time + 1
OR out_time                     IS NULL;
```

**Working Demo:**

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 1 ID, SYSDATE -1 in_time, SYSDATE + 2/24 out_time FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 1,    SYSDATE -10,        SYSDATE + 2/24 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 2,    SYSDATE -1/24,      SYSDATE + 2/24 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 2,    SYSDATE -1/24,      NULL FROM dual
  6  )
  7  -- end of sample_Data mimicking a real table
  8  SELECT *
  9  FROM sample_data
 10  WHERE TO_CHAR(in_time, 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(out_time, 'MMYYYY')
 11  AND out_time                     > in_time + 1
 12  OR out_time                     IS NULL;

        ID IN_TIME              OUT_TIME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 15-DEC-2015 10:49:27 16-DEC-2015 12:49:27
         1 06-DEC-2015 10:49:27 16-DEC-2015 12:49:27
         2 16-DEC-2015 09:49:27
```

If you want to restrict it to a particular month and year, just add another condition:

```
AND TO_CHAR(in_time, 'MMYYYY') = '112015'
```

As Sentinel points out, using **TO_CHAR** on the column would suppress any regular index on the `in_time` column, not efficient in terms of performance. The better way would be to use a **range** condition.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2      SELECT 1 ID, SYSDATE -1 in_time, SYSDATE + 2/24 out_time FROM dual UNION ALL
  3      SELECT 1,    SYSDATE -10,        SYSDATE + 2/24 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4      SELECT 2,    SYSDATE -1/24,      SYSDATE + 2/24 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5      SELECT 2,    SYSDATE -1/24,      NULL FROM dual
  6      )
  7  -- end of sample_Data mimicking a real table
  8  SELECT *
  9  FROM sample_data
 10  WHERE in_time >= to_date('112015','mmyyyy')
 11  AND in_time < add_months(to_date('112015','mmyyyy'), 1)
 12  AND (out_time  > in_time + 1
 13  OR out_time  IS NULL);

        ID IN_TIME              OUT_TIME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 15-DEC-2015 11:38:20 16-DEC-2015 13:38:20
         1 06-DEC-2015 11:38:20 16-DEC-2015 13:38:20
         2 16-DEC-2015 10:38:20
```

Comment: Converting in_time to a string value will prevent the DB from using any non function based indexes that may exist on the in_time column.  In general it's better not to change the data type of table column, but instead to change the data types of the constants or variables you are comparing them to.  In this case that means using some form of ranged comparison rather than an equality check.

Comment: @Sentinel Agreed. I myself would have suggested the range condition in order to use any regular index on the in_time column. However, the important thing was to focus on the logic. No that you have mentioned it, I would edit the answer to add the performance part too.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work.

```
select *
  from your_table 
 where to_date('112015','mmyyyy') <= in_time
   and in_time < to_date('112015','mmyyyy') + interval '1' month
   and (out_time is null or in_time - out_time > 1);
```

If there are any indexes on the in_time column it's better to not convert it to a string for comparison to your '112015' string.  Instead converting  '112015' to a date value (which defaults to the first of the month) and using a partially closed range comparison with the converted date and one month out will enable such an index to be used.